# GoogleSignIn Works But Google_DEFAULT_GAMES Doesn't

Tags: java, android, google-play-games, android-googleapiclient

When I call GoogleSignInOptions from the default sign-in option, I get a signIn UI displayed

```
GoogleSignInOptions ClientInfo = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder.(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().build();
GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignInClient.getClient(this, ClientInfo);
Intent SignInintent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
startActivityForResult(SignInintent,3000);
```

However if I call GoogleSignInOptions with the default games sign in. I get no UI displayed at all infact I get a dim light as if it wants to display but then it dissappears.

```
GoogleSignInOptions ClientInfo = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder. GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().build();
GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignInClient.getClient(this, ClientInfo);
Intent SignInintent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
startActivityForResult(SignInintent,3000);
```

Comment: If you refer to [this thread from github](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4509), It seems that one possible reason is that the keystore SHA-1 was mismatched compared to the console. Check your settings and compare SHA-1 key (both release and debug), `applicationId` of `build.gradle` and other settings. There could be some mismatched.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The checks for SHA-1, packageName, and other possible problems listed in https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting did not produce any effective results. My problem was solved by moving app_id written directly to the metadata in string resources. Really, i don't know why but it works.

**Before:**

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="XXXXXXXXXXXX" />
```

**After:**

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

res/values/games_ids:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- app_id -->
    <string name="app_id" translatable="false">XXXXXXXXXXXX</string>
</resources>
```